# Flutter: set appbar custom title height

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-appbar

In App bar i added search widget like this:

```
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Color.fromARGB(50, 255, 255, 255),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
      ),
      child: Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0),
              child: TextFormField(...
                    )),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    ),
    bottom: PreferredSize(
      preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(100.0),
      child: TabBar(...
```

I added margin from top equal 30 but search section is cropped:

[image]

How can i increase default `title` **size** in appbar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use flexibleSpace instead of title.

```
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    flexibleSpace: Container(....
```

Answer (score 0):

`flexibleSpace` works fine but another way is to use `PreferredSize`.

```
Scaffold(
  appBar: PreferredSize(
    preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(100.0),
    child:AppBar(
      title:Text("title"),
    )
  ),
  body:...
 )
```

Comment: with `PreferredSize` you can not add `title` with custom height

Comment: @sayreskabir yes. it just increases the height of its wrapper.